# WebApi returning wrong status code

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I have an operation handler that checks for authentication and throws an exception when authentication fails using

```
throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

However this still returns a 404 Not Found status code to the client/test client.

This is my operation handler

```
public class AuthOperationHandler : HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, HttpRequestMessage>
{
    RequireAuthorizationAttribute _authorizeAttribute;

    public AuthOperationHandler(RequireAuthorizationAttribute authorizeAttribute) : base("response")
    {
        _authorizeAttribute = authorizeAttribute;
    }

    protected override HttpRequestMessage OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage input)
    {
        IPrincipal user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

        if (_authorizeAttribute.Roles == null)
            return input;

        var roles = _authorizeAttribute.Roles.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (roles.Any(role => user.IsInRole(role)))
            return input;

        throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good and bad news for you.  The framework your are using has evolved into [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).  Unfortunately, OperationHandlers no longer exist.  Their closest equivalent are ActionFilters.

Having said that, WCF Web API never supported throwing WebFaultException, that is a vestige of WCF's SOAP heritage.  I think the exception was called  HttpWebException, however, I never used it, I just set the status code on the response.

Comment: That doesn't bode well, i was going to migrate my api (based on preview 6) to the beta tomorrow. I have an operation handler based validation handler :(

Comment: @AntonyScott  ActionFilters are capable of doing most of what you could do with OperationHandlers.

Comment: hmm okay. looks like I've got a bit of a rewrite tomorrow then :)

Comment: I just saw a presentation from Scott Gu on Asp.Net WebApi and I will be stopping any further development in WCF WebApi anyway so this is affectively not an issue any more. I can just use the built in ActionFilters from MVC with the new WebApi, which is also a better solution as I am mainly an MVC guy, so smiles all round :) Also thanks for the info @DarrelMiller